# Public Void to display message after trigger event not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I apologize if my title doesn't make sense but moving on my problem:
I'm using c# in Unity and using the code:

```
public void LevelComplete()
{
    Debug.Log("LEVEL FINISHED");
}
```

this next bit is from a different script

```
public class EndTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
   public GameManager gameManager;

   void onTriggerEnter()
   {
      gameManager.LevelComplete();
   }
}
```

Whats supposed to happen is just a simple message in the console saying "level finished" but nothing is 
coming up.

I have the end the game by having a box all the way at the end and when you pass it, you trigger the Level complete thing.
I checked to see if I have is trigger enabled and have a rigid body on the end box but no message is coming up.

Answer (score 1):

Two reasons:

- It is [`OnTriggerEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter.html) with capital `O`
- The signature has to match `void OnTriggerEnter(Collider)`

For all the built-in message methods of Unity the correct spelling and signatures are essential!
Otherwise it is not recognized by Unity and not called when you collide with the trigger.

```
public class EndTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
   public GameManager gameManager;

   private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
   {
      gameManager.LevelComplete();
   }
}
```

If this still doesn't work refer to the API:

> Note: Both `GameObjects`
>    must contain a `Collider` component. One must have `Collider.isTrigger` enabled, and contain a `Rigidbody`. If both `GameObjects` have `Collider.isTrigger` enabled, no collision happens. The same applies when both `GameObjects` do not have a `Rigidbody` component.